# Sendmail.php sends mail without topic message or sender name, what is wrong?

Tags: php, sendmail

I have simple form to sendmail. I receive e-mails but there is no name no message also no topic. Problem was worse I wasn't available to receive e-mail but after I add the line `$headers = implode("\r\n", $headers);` I just start to receive e-mail but unknown sender no topic and no message

Here it is sendemail.php

```
<?php
$name       = $_POST['name'];
$from       = $_POST['email'];
$subject    = $_POST['subject']; 
$message    = $_POST['message'];
$to         = 'tradertarik@gmail.com';

$headers   = array();
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";
$headers[] = "From: {$name} <{$from}>";
$headers[] = "Reply-To: <{$from}>";
$headers[] = "Subject: {$subject}";
$headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();
$headers = implode("\r\n", $headers);

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
die;
```

and here is the HTML code for form. Maybe there is a problem here.

```
    <div class="contact-form wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="600ms">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <form id="main-contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php">
            <div class="row  wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" required>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Enter your message" required></textarea>
            </div>                        
            <div class="form-group">
              <button type="submit" class="btn-submit">Send Now</button>
            </div>
          </form>   
        </div>
```

Comment: You should start with checking your `$_POST` array and see if it really contains the expected values `var_dump($_POST);`. Also, I think you need to add an extra `\r\n` to the headers: `$headers = implode("\r\n", $headers) . '\r\n'`. The last `\r\n` will terminate the headers in the request.

Comment: It seems that your code is vulnerable to [email injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_injection).

Comment: Look at the form action your are using "sendemail.php".
And look at the page name "sendmail.php". 
Do verify that!!!

Comment: sendemail.php file name I wrote on question wrong but it is correct on file name. If it was the problem I will not available to receive e-mail. I receive e-mail but there is no information on it jus empty e-mail no name no message no topic.

Comment: Cylone I have tried what you recommend but no result even these changes stop to send mail.

Comment: Pang I still to try to understand what it means e-mail injection attack. I will check on it.